# Representing a sentence using propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, binary-operations, artificial-intelligence

I am confused regarding a propositional logic representation of a sentence.

Please note that this sentence is not realistic:

"A person who is male (M) is smart (S) if he is tall (T), but otherwise is not smart."

Which of the following propositional logic formulas correctly represents the above:

(a) $(M \wedge S) \iff T$

(b) $M \Rightarrow (S \iff T)$

Note that $\Rightarrow$ and $\iff$ represents "only if/implies" and "iff and only if," respectively.

The solution to the problem is (b)

The solution claims that (a) is NOT an option because it asserts, among other things, that all tall people are male, which is not what is asserted. This makes sense to me, I think (not confident, but this is not the main point of this post).

The solution claims that (b) IS a correct representation because it is saying that if a person is male, then they are smart IF AND ONLY IF they are tall. I don't understand that, and based on my current understanding, I don't agree with this because the "IFF" part is saying that if the person is tall, then they are smart, and that is not what the problem statement said. The problem statement only states that a person who is male is smart if he is tall.

So I feel like (b) is not correct, but if you swap out the $\iff$ for $\Rightarrow$ then it becomes correct.

Am I misunderstanding something here?

Answer (score 2):

In words, we have:

> A person who is male (M) is smart (S) if he is tall (T), but otherwise is not smart.

Or equivalently:

> A person who is male (M) is smart (S) if he is tall (T), but otherwise **if he is not tall, then he** is not smart.

Inserted phrase in bold is implicitly understood.

Symbolically, by the contrapositive rule and  by the definition of '$\iff$', we have:

$(T\implies S)\land (\neg T \implies \neg S)$

$\equiv \space \space (T \implies S )\land (S \implies T)$

$\equiv \space \space T \iff S$

$\equiv \space \space S \iff T $

Comment: Yes, I am of the relations, but I'm not sure how this helps. Could you explain further? In the middle expression, $T \Rightarrow S$ is saying that a tall person is smart, right? If so, that's not what the sentence is asserting?

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I am misunderstanding the "but otherwise is not smart" part. Is that what makes the "only if" "IFF?"

Comment: I've thought about this some more, and it still doesn't make sense. At first I thought the "but otherwise is not smart" is manifested in $\lnot S \implies \lnot T$, but when I think about "but otherwise is not smart," I'm interpreting it as saying "if the male person is not tall, then he is not smart." Wouldn't that make it $\lnot T \implies \lnot S$?

Comment: Indeed, @lamanon , the original sentence says "smart if tall but not smart if otherwise" which is  $(T\to S)\wedge(\neg T\to\neg S)$.  That still equates to $(S\leftrightarrow T)$

Comment: @Iamanon  "A person who is male (M) is smart (S) if he is tall (T), but otherwise **if he is *not* tall, then he** is *not* smart." (Inserted phrase in bold is implicit.)

Comment: Extensive edits.

Answer (score 1):

> The solution claims that (b) IS a correct representation because it is saying that if a person is male, then they are smart IF AND ONLY IF they are tall. I don't understand that, and based on my current understanding, I don't agree with this because the "IFF" part is saying that if the person is tall, then they are smart, and that is not what the problem statement said. The problem statement only states that a person who is male is smart if he is tall.

No, there is that "otherwise" clause in the statement.

The sentence says that "A male person is: smart if tall, and *not smart if otherwise* (ie not tall)."

That claims that "A male person is smart *exactly when* tall."

$$M\to(S\leftrightarrow T)$$

Comment: I think I'm struggling with the semantics here for some reason. "smart if tall" is the same as saying "smart only if tall" and "if tall, then smart" right? In propositional logic form, it's $T \implies S$?

Comment: On second thought "smart if tall" $\neq$  "smart only if tall"

Comment: "Smart if tall" is "If tall, then smart", ie: $T\to S$.  That is also "Tall only if smart" and "Not tall if not smart" ie: $\neg S\to\neg T$.

Comment: Got it. If it's "Smart only if tall" then that's manifested in $S \implies T$ and it also means "if smart, then tall," right? I think I struggle with the different ways to phrase things. The "if ___ then ___" format is more intuitive to me than "____ if _____" or "___ only if ____"

Comment: Indeed, it confuses many.

Comment: Looking back at your earlier comment, I'm not sure how "Not tall if not smart" came about. I understand that $\lnot S \implies \lnot T$ came from $T\implies S$ using the contrapositive rule , and it reads as "if not smart, then not tall." But without the mathematical stuff, I don't quite understand how we jumped from "If tall, then smart" to "If not smart, then not tall." Is it possible to explain without equations?

Comment: Take "If they are tall, then they are smart" as a promise. That promises that they *cannot* be tall should they *not* be smart. Thus the promise entails that "if they are *not* smart, then they are *not* tall."  *Et vice versa*.